# Cannot modify table class using javascript and bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

I tried to modify my table class using javascript but somehow the table appearance doesn't change. Here is my code :

```
function OpenDataJS(){
    var selectobj = document.getElementById("user_data");
    for (var i=0; i<selectobj.length; i++){
        selectobj.remove(i);
    }
    var object;
    $.ajax({
        url : "Controller/OpenData",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
        success : function(response) {
            object = response;
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },async : false     
    });

    for(var key in object) {
        var tr_temp = document.createElement('TR');
        tr_temp.setAttribute('id',"log-tr-"+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        tr_temp.setAttribute('name',"log-tr-"+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        document.getElementById("user_data").appendChild(tr_temp);
        $("log-tr-"+String(parseInt(key)+1)).addClass('table-dark');
        var td_temp = document.createElement('TD');
        td_temp.setAttribute('id',"no_"+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        td_temp.setAttribute('name',"no_"+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        td_temp.setAttribute('scope','col');
        td_temp.innerText = parseInt(key)+1;
        document.getElementById("log-tr-"+String(parseInt(key)+1)).appendChild(td_temp);
        for(var key2 in object[key]){
            var td_temp = document.createElement('TD');
            td_temp.setAttribute('id',key2+"_"+String(parseInt(key)+1));
            td_temp.setAttribute('name',key2+"_"+String(parseInt(key)+1));
            td_temp.setAttribute('scope','col');
            td_temp.innerText = object[key][key2];
            document.getElementById("log-tr-"+String(parseInt(key)+1)).appendChild(td_temp);
        }
        var btn_temp = document.createElement('input');
        btn_temp.type = "button";
        btn_temp.setAttribute('id','editbtn_'+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        btn_temp.setAttribute('name','editbtn_'+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        btn_temp.setAttribute('value','Edit');
        btn_temp.setAttribute('onClick',"edit_data(this.id);");
        btn_temp.setAttribute('class',"btn btn-dark");
        document.getElementById("log-tr-"+String(parseInt(key)+1)).appendChild(btn_temp);
                
        var btn_temp = document.createElement('input');
        btn_temp.type = "button";
        btn_temp.setAttribute('id','delbtn_'+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        btn_temp.setAttribute('name','delbtn_'+String(parseInt(key)+1));
        btn_temp.setAttribute('value','Delete');
        btn_temp.setAttribute('onClick',"delete_data(this.id);");
        btn_temp.setAttribute('class',"btn btn-dark");
        document.getElementById("log-tr-"+String(parseInt(key)+1)).appendChild(btn_temp);
    }
    var table_user = document.getElementById("user_data");
    table_user.setAttribute('class',"table table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered");
```

From code above I change the class using this lines of code :
`var table_user = document.getElementById("user_data"); table_user.setAttribute('class',"table table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered");`

I don't put any css on my code. I use bootstrap 5 with this :

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Why the table appearance doesn't change to dark but only the header?

The table appeearance should be dark because I changed it's class to dark.

Comment: Stop using `async: false`, this is deprecated. Move all the code that uses the result of the AJAX call into the `success:` function.

Comment: Since you haven't included the CSS, it's impossible to tell why the class isn't doing what you want. Please post a [mre].

Comment: The MRE can leave out all the AJAX stuff. Just include the code that changes the class of the table.